# Find character in tree with SML

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, sml

I'm new to SML and trying to wrap my head around functional programming. I want to have a function that accepts a tree `t` and a character `c` and returns true or false if the tree contains the character.

The algorithm I want to implement is:

1. if leaf is null return false,
2. else if character is in leaf return true,
3. return result of left tree or result of right tree

This is my tree datatype

```
datatype 'a tree =
    Leaf of 'a
  | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree;
```

And this is the function

```
fun containsChar (Leaf t, c: char) = false 
  | containsChar (Node (left, t, right)) = 
    if t = c then true else false
  | containsChar (Node (left, t, right)) = (containsChar left) <> (containsChar right);
```

I am getting `Unbound value identifier "c".` Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing called "c" in that clause. There is a "c" in the leaf case, but that's a completely different case. You forgot that parameter in the other cases.
(And `if t = c then true else false` is equivalent to `t = c`.)

You also have identical patterns in the second and third clauses, which isn't going to work.

Another problem you have is the "leaf is null" rule – a leaf can't be "null".
I suspect that this is what brought you astray, as the result of your first clause  is `false` even though the argument is clearly an existing leaf, and your second clause is clearly not a leaf but looks like your second rule.

Your rules should be these:

A tree contains a character if and only if

- it is the value in a leaf, or
- it is the value in a node, or
- it is contained in a node's subtrees.

In ML (removing the restriction to `char Tree` since it seems arbitrary),

```
fun contains (Leaf t, c) = t = c 
  | contains (Node (left, t, right), c) = t = c
                                       orelse contains(left, c)
                                       orelse contains(right, c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are very helpful.I guess my confusion is in determining a base case where there are no more nodes to traverse. In Java, we'd say `if (node == null)`. How is that determined in your function?

Comment: @agomez A tree is either a node or a leaf (this is what your definition says). Those are the only cases, and there are no more nodes to traverse when you have reached a leaf. Things can't be "nothing" in SML.

Answer (score 0):

You could generalise the function once more to

```
fun any p Leaf = false
  | any p (Node (left, x, right)) =
      p x orelse any p left orelse any p right

fun contains c t = any (fn x => c = x) t
```